Haystack 2 with Elasticsearch complex document
I have Elasticsearch storage with a movies index which is populated with documents like that:
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  title: "Some film",
  actors: [ { _id: ObjectId, title: "Actor A" }, { _id: ObjectId, title: "Actor B" } ]
}

Can I use haystack to run queries like "Who're the actors in Some film" or "What films did Actor A play in?"? Haystack 1 had search_fields argument in ElasticsearchDocumentStore but it was removed in version 2.
Sorry for dumb question, I'm very new in that.

I suggest that you re-index the documents with Haystack's DocumentWriter. That allows you to define "title" as the text content of the Document and actors as metadata. If you then write your Documents to an ElasticsearchDocumentStore, you can use an ElasticsearchEmbeddingRetriever or a ElasticsearchBM25Retriever with metadata filters. Here is an explanation of how metadata filtering is done in Haystack: https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/metadata-filtering
If you switch to an OpenSearchDocumentStore you get even more flexibility. You could then initialize an OpenSearchBM25Retriever or an OpenSearchEmbeddingRetriever with a custom_query.
